# How to get Process Finish Button event in Dynamics CRM?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365

I am using Dynamics 365 online instance to integrate sales process. I have one condition where I need to change the Probability field value to 100 when user clicks on Finish button in Close Process Stage.

[image]

I have done some research and found that (**OnProcessStatusChange event**) can help to get business process flow status change (statuses: Active, **Finished**, or Aborted)

Ref Link: [OnProcessStatusChangeEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn817874.aspx)

I have checked this by adding this to form OnLoad event like below, but nothing happens.

```
Xrm.Page.data.process.addOnProcessStatusChange(setProbablityOnFinish);
```

Is there any other solution?

Comment: Does the eventhandler ‘setProbablityOnFinish’ exist?

Comment: Yes ‘setProbablityOnFinish’ is already there which i haven't mentioned in my post.

Comment: any error on browser console? Debug result?

Comment: HI Vinoth, Did you find any solution for this ? I want to trigger one java script function when user clicks on finish button in side of a business flow ? Is this possible ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you implement the `eventhandler` like this, it will work.

```
function OnLoad() {
   Xrm.Page.data.process.addOnProcessStatusChange(statusOnChange);
}

function statusOnChange() {
   status = Xrm.Page.data.process.getStatus();
   if (status == "finished") {
       //Write your logic here//
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vinoth its working. I created a new Web Resource and try this.